# Python error : 'tuple' object is not callable on xlxswriter

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I m trying to write some data in an excel file.

```
rounds= [[(0, 2), (1, 3)], [(2, 0), (1, 3)], [(2, 1), (0, 3)], [(0, 3), (2, 1)], [(3, 0), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (3, 1)]]
```

And I want to write them in a list as below:
(round is the index of the sub-list they belong)

| pl1 | pl2 | round |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 | 2 |

and so on.....

I'm trying to move the data to the excel file using xlxswrite, but I get this error

(Please, ignore that I don't put headers in excel columns, I know)

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("table.xls")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

rounds= [[(0, 2), (1, 3)], [(2, 0), (1, 3)], [(2, 1), (0, 3)], [(0, 3), (2, 1)], [(3, 0), (1, 2)], [(2, 0), (3, 1)]]

for index,entry in enumerate(rounds):
    for pairing in entry:
        worksheet.write(index,0,pairing(0))
        worksheet.write(index,0,pairing(1))
        worksheet.write(index,0,str(index))
```

But I get the error :

> worksheet.write(index,0,pairing(0))
> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

How can I access the data of each tuple then?

Comment: You need square brackets like `pairing[0]`. Better yet, you can directly unpack the tuples: `for a, b in entry:` and then set the values like so: `worksheet.write(index, 0, a); worksheet.write(index, 0, b)`.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Oh, thank you , you are correct! I also have another question. It only writes the second tuple's data of each sub-list, why could that be ?

Comment: I realize that I never "jump" to the next row, but how do I do it for the next "couple" ?